# How to reduce poly count for subdivision modifier

Tags: subdivision-surface, polycount

Im watching a Maya tutorial by 3dex for a backpack and he was able to apply his modifier and keep a low poly count. Is there any way to do this in blender (I am planning on making a low poly and high poly model to bake in substance painter). Ive attached pictures of what my model looks like with the modifier applied (high poly) and what it looks like in edit mode before applying the modifier (low poly). Ive also attached the Maya reference. Thank you.
[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT:

Ive tried baking my low poly with the high poly (hp being the subdivided model) and it seems to have no effect. Im still new to substance so sorry if this is ignorant. Ive included references of the 3d ex tutorial so you can see what his looks like in relation to my model in substance painter.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The modifier isn't applied in maya. As we can see in the screenshot it's just the low poly version of the backpack and the modifier has been removed, slightly different workflow in maya.

Comment: @brockmann I know about the decimated modifier, I guess I was just confused on the Maya workflow since I've never used it and in the tutorial the low poly version seemed the not have polygon shading that you would find in a low poly model

Comment: Other than in blender the shading is set to smooth by default in maya. Just export 2 versions (the low poly and one with the subsurf applied) and use the high poly for baking in painter.

Comment: @brockmann thanks, is there a way to check the question as answered , sometimes I get a check mark on the left hand side but it isn't showing up right now

Comment: No problem. IMHO a [XY question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) so I think closing as duplicate is the most appropriate in this case (same question overall). You can not accept comments, you can only upvote comments the same way you can upvote answers that you find useful. I recommend have a look into: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/